# Does Windows 7 Ultimate Lite support Visual Studio 2008 & 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, windows-7

Does Windows 7 Ultimate Lite support Visual Studio 2008 & 2010? I'm planning to install these on my notebook.

Comment: What's Windows 7 Ultimate Lite?

Comment: @SLaks: It's called Windows XP. :P

Comment: I *think* Windows 7 Ultimate Lite is a hacked, unauthorized version of Ultimate, with a bunch of "unnecessary" pieces stripped out. Or that's what Google's implying.

Comment: Isn't a better question "Does Visual Studio 2008 and 2010 support Windows 7 Ultimate Lite"?  The answer to that is clear: No since "Windows 7 Ultimate Lite" isn't a real SKU of Windows.

Comment: @Larry Osterman, yes that will be better phrased question, @Michael Petrotta yes 7 ultimate lite is stripped down custom build version one of my pal created it or better downloaded it and ask me to try it out in my laptop :-(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update: Sorry I didn't see the keyword **Lite**, it's my bad, and my answer might be wrong,

---

Sure, you can do it.There is no problem to install Visual Studio 2010.

Before you install Visual Studio 2008, it's better to turn off the UAC in Windows 7.
http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-disable-and-turn-off-uac-in-windows-7/

After you install Visual Studio 2008 remember to provide the Administrator privilege to run "devenv.exe" in "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\"